# Reverse a given sentence in Java

Tags: java, string, reverse

Can anyone tell me how to write a Java program to reverse a given sentence?

For example, if the input is:

> "This is an interview question"

The output must be:

> "question interview an is this"

Comment: You should probably consider taking Java certification classes, as they will teach you commonly used Java library classes. You'll then have the tools needed to accomplish such tasks.

Comment: Reverse the string first. Reverse the words then. It takes two pass but very clean. Can be done in 1 pass as well.

Comment: @jack, I think your first word was meant to be "split", yes?

Comment: @CPerkins: well, "the question" -> "noitseuq eht" -> "question the" still works, and I suspect that is what Jack meant since answerers have already posted your way.

Comment: @CPerkins No.  What I meant was (in python):<br>
  str = "this is interview question" <br>
  str1 = str[::-1] <br>
  print str1 <br>
  for word in str1.split(" "): <br>
    print word[::-1] <br>

Comment: for exa: this is interview question =>
noitseuq weivretni si siht => question interview is this

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1009160/466738

Answer (score 24):

You split the string by the space then iterate over it backwards to assemble the reversed sentence.

```
String[] words =  "This is interview question".split(" ");

String rev = "";
for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
   rev += words[i] + " ";
}

// rev = "question interview is This "

// can also use StringBuilder:
StringBuilder revb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
   revb.append(words[i]);
   revb.append(" ");
}
// revb.toString() = "question interview is This "
```

Comment: Won't this add a trailing space?

Comment: Is there a reason you're concatenating to a `string` (which creates a new `string` object every time) instead of using a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @Christopher Parker - Simply showing the principle. This can of course be adapted to be more performant (if needed).

Comment: @Skilldrick - `Rev.trim();` to remove the trailing space. Not that the question specified, but like you, I dislike extra spaces like that.

Comment: I wouldn't use trim() - It creates an entirely new String.  Better to perform a second check of i within the loop IMHO.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/60913/146446 explains this code in more detail, and also has great unit tests.

Answer (score 24):

```
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
String[] reversedWords = ArrayUtils.reverse(words);
String reversedSentence = StringUtils.join(reversedWords, " ");
```

(using [`ArrayUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) and `StringUtils` from commons-lang, but these are easy methods to write - just a few loops)

Comment: Using an outside library for an interview question this simple isn't going go over that well.

Comment: well. that over go to going isn't simple this question interview an for library outside an Using

Comment: @D'Nabre - if you know commons-lang well enough to write that code, I think it would go VERY well over that well.

Comment: @D'Nabre I don't think so. If they ask you to explain how are these utility methods implemented, you'd always be able to explain, but thus you are increasing the elegance of your code. What if these methdos were present in `java.util.Arrays`?

Comment: If someone demonstrated appreciation of the *know and use the libraries* guideline in an interview, I'd definitely consider that a plus.

Comment: The last line should use `StringUtils` rather than `ArrayUtils`.

Comment: Here in India they tell you "please do not use any library methods, it won't be considered" that in fact wont go well.

Comment: Not sure if this solution takes care of double spaces?

Comment: for double-spaces you can split around " +". Or normalize first.

Answer (score 21):

Just being different: a recursive solution. Doesn't add any extra spaces.

```
public static String reverse(String s) {
   int k = s.indexOf(" ");
   return k == -1 ? s : reverse(s.substring(k + 1)) + " " + s.substring(0, k);
}


System.out.println("[" + reverse("This is interview question") + "]");
// prints "[question interview is This]"
```

---

I will also improve on the `split` solution by using `\b` instead (it's so obvious!).

```
    String[] parts = "Word boundary is better than space".split("\\b");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = parts.length; i --> 0 ;) {
        sb.append(parts[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("[" + sb.toString() + "]");
    // prints "[space than better is boundary Word]"
```

Comment: nice, i really liked the recursive solution design, but the iteration + string builder has to be faster, correct?

Answer (score 6):

Just split it on a space character into a string array, then loop over the array in reverse order and construct the output string.

```
String input = "This is interview question";
String output = "";
String[] array = input.split(" ");
for(int i = array.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    output += array[i];
    if (i != 0) { output += " "; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Bozho already gave a great Java-specific answer, but in the event you ever need to solve this problem without Java API methods:

To reverse, you can simply pop individual words onto a [`stack`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) and pop them all back off when there are no words left.

(Just to be extra clear, Java does provide a [`Stack` class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), so it is possible to use this method in Java as well).

Answer (score 3):

a every boring bit of java:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("this is an interview question".split("\\s")));
Collections.reverse(l);
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
for( String s : l ){
    b.append(s).append(' ');
}
b.toString().trim();
```

in groovy it's a little bit more readable:

```
"this is an interview question"
    .split("\\s")
    .reverse()
    .join(' ')
```

Comment: @Oded's is a lot nicer...way to used to just using collections.

Answer (score 3):

I also give it a try: Here's a version using a stack and a scanner:

```
String input = "this is interview question";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

while(sc.hasNext()) {
    stack.push(sc.next());
}

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for(;;) { // forever
    output.append(stack.pop());

    if(stack.isEmpty()) {
        break; // end loop
    } else {
        output.append(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ReverseString {

    public void reverse(String[] source) {

        String dest = "";
        for (int n = source.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
            dest += source[n] + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(dest);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ReverseString rs = new ReverseString();
        String[] str = "What is going on".split(" ");
        rs.reverse(str);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

nicer approach probably.. had seen the logic somewhere..here is my code which might do the job.

```
    public class revWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        revWords obj = new revWords();
        String print = obj.reverseWords("I am God");
        System.out.println(print);

    }

    public String reverseWords(String words)
    {
      if(words == null || words.isEmpty() || !words.contains(" "))
        return words;

      String reversed = "";
      for( String word : words.split(" "))
        reversed = word + " " + reversed;

      return reversed;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think you should use any library..
>   1) Reverse whole string 
>   2) Reverse each word.

```
public static void revWord(char[] a) {

    // reverse whole
    revWord(a, 0, a.length);

    int st = -1;
    int end = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        if (st == -1 && a[i] != ' ') {
            st = i;
        }
        if (end == -1 && a[i] == ' ' ) {
            end = i;
        }
        if(i == a.length-1){
            end=i+1;
        }

        if (st != -1 && end != -1) {
            revWord(a, st, end );

            st = -1;
            end = -1;
        }

    }

}

public static void revWord(char[] a, int s, int l) {
    int mid = (l - s) / 2;
    l--;

    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++, l--) {
        char t = a[s+i];
        a[s+i] = a[l];
        a[l] = t;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: This will work with ascii charset only... not ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

No one has mentioned a vanilla Java 8 based solution yet, which is the same as [Bozho's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2713676/521799), but without any third-party libraries. So here it is:

```
String input = "This is interview question";

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

Answer (score 1):

please try below solution, this is working for me.

```
public class reverseline {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String str="This is interview question";
    String words[]=str.split(" ");
    for(int i=words.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        System.out.print(words[i]+" ");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) was declared legacy, many used *StringTokenizer* for this. Thought I would just leave it here.

```
String sentence = "This is interview question";
String reversed = "";
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(sentence); 

while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) { // Loop through each token
    reversed =  tokens.nextToken() + ' ' + reversed; //add to start
}

System.out.println(reversed.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest Answer

```
public class ReverseSentence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String inputString = sc.nextLine();

        String[] words = inputString.split(" ");

        List<String> reverseWord = Arrays.asList(words);
        Collections.reverse(reverseWord);

        Iterator itr = reverseWord.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.print(itr.next() + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

**OR**

```
public class ReverseSentence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String inputString = sc.nextLine();

        String[] words = inputString.split(" ");

        for (int i = words.length-1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(words[i] +" ");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works very well, all we need to do is

1. Split the words in an array
2. Add them backwards in a list
3. Dont add extra space if its last character
4. Print the list

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    String words= "Hello to this World";

    String[]split=  words.split(" ");
    List<String> newList = new LinkedList<>();

    //Put the strings from array in list but in reverse order, avoid adding spaces for the last word.

    for(int i=split.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(i==0)
            newList.add(split[i]);
        else
            newList.add(split[i]+" ");
    }
    for(String s : newList){
        System.out.print(s);
    }
   ```

   }