# what is the simple way to reverse the words in string in java?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, reverse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reverse a given sentence in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713655/reverse-a-given-sentence-in-java)

what is the simple way to reverse the words in string in java?
Example: 
"Hello Stack over flow" will turn to: 
"flow over Stack Hello"

Thank you,

Comment: There are several solutions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713655/reverse-a-given-sentence-in-java).

Comment: [Reverse string java](http://chinmaylokesh.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/program-to-reverse-words-in-a-sentence-c-and-java/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
    String s = "Hello stack over flow";
    List< String > words = Arrays.asList( s.split( " " ) );
    Collections.reverse( words );
    String reversed = words.get( 0 );
    for ( int i = 1; i < words.size(); ++i ) {
        reversed += " " + words.get( i );
    }
```

I assume that all characters except spaces are considered as part of words. You may need to provide more details if you need something else.

Answer (score 1):

`String s="abcd";`

`StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(s);`

`sb=sb.reverse();`

`System.out.println(sb.toString());`

Hope can help you.

Comment: Really, try your method with `String s  = "Hello stack overflow users"`.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution would be [splitting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the input string at the whitespaces, then reversing the result array with eg. [Collections.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)  or Commons [ArrayUtils.reverse()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#reverse%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29), then [joining](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) them back together.