# How to print the mirror of String in java without effecting the words?

Tags: java, string

I have a `String str="Ram Is A Good Boy";`

I want the output

> Boy Good A Is Ram

Please give me a code for this approach??

Comment: You might want to use a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: Please check this once http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713655/reverse-a-given-sentence-in-java

Comment: Try it first yourself.

Comment: please try something and post the prob you face

Comment: Read about [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and make a try, then come back.

Comment: You should not put simple programming questions here without try it out.

Comment: People here are to help solve your problems, not to solve your problems. Show some efforts first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = "Ram Is A Good Boy";
String [] strArray = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=strArray.length-1;i>-1;i--)
{
    sb.append(strArray[i]+" ");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Not giving the direct solution but if you follow the steps below, you'll achieve what you want.

1. [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) with space.
2. print the splitted values in reverse order.

But on second thought your mirror image is wrong.

> Ram Is A Good Boy | yoB dooG A sI maR

isn't that correct mirror for the given string?

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="Ram Is A Good Boy";
String splits[] = str.split(" ");
string reverse = "";
for(int i = splits.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    reverse += splits[i] + " ";
}
System.out.println(reverse);
```