# Reversing the Sentence in java

Tags: java

I m inserting a string in my program

```
String str = " I live in India";
```

how can in get reversed string of that like

```
String str ="India in live I"
```

this is an interview question in my interview. Please any one can help me out in this question

Comment: What you have tried..?Please give here

Comment: Welcome to SO. This seems to be homework, what have you tried?

Comment: Convert the Sentence to word array , reverse the array , join the strings - one possible way. Use ur imagination.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713655/reverse-a-given-sentence-in-java

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Split it and then add it to a new `String` in reverse order.

```
String s = " I live in India";
String[] split = s.split(" ");
String result = "";
for (int i = split.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  result += (split[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println(result.trim());
```

This prints:

```
India in live I
```

Although short and straight-forward, this solution is not really effective in terms of time and memory. It somewhat depends on how the input is given (as a `String` or as something else) and whether we can modify the input in order to save computation resources.

Let's assume the sentence is given as an array of characters and we are allowed to modify it. We can then follow the following approach, which brings linear time (`O(n)`) and constant (`O(1)`) memory complexity:

What we will have as input would be:

```
char[] array = {'I',' ','l','i','v','e',' ','i','n',' ','I','n','d','i','a'};
```

Let's write a method that takes a `char[]` array and reverses the elements from `start` to `end` in-place:

```
void reverse(char[] array, int start, int end) {
  while (start < end) {
    char temp = array[start];
    array[start] = array[end];
    array[end] = temp;
    start++;
    end--;
  }
}
```

First, we will reverse the whole array (in-place), using this method.
You can notice that after the reversal the words in the sentence are ordered in the desired (reversed) way. The problem is that each word is reversed:

```
{'a','i','d','n','I',' ','n','i',' ','e','v','i','l',' ','I'}
```

Let's now iterate the array from left to the right. We will reverse each word in-place, like we initially reversed the whole array. In order to do that, we need to keep an index (`start`), telling where does a word start and every time we encounter a space (`' '`) we will trigger a reverse between `start` and the character before the space. This way we will keep the desired order of words, but we will also have the characters in the words properly ordered.

The code should be self-explanatory:

```
void reverseSentence(char[] array) {
  int n = array.length;
  reverse(array, 0, n - 1);
  int start = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (array[i] == ' ') {
      reverse(array, start, i - 1);
      start = i + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Calling this on the initial `array`, we get:

```
{'I','n','d','i','a',' ','i','n',' ','l','i','v','e', ' ','I'}
```

We can further construct a `String` out of it, or just print it. In any case, the sentence is reversed as desired.

This has linear complexity (`O(n)`), because each character is part of a reverse exactly once and is being tested for being a space exactly once.

As for memory-usage, we used only one additional variable (`start`), which makes the total memory complexity a constant (`O(1)`).

Comment: you could have used string builder when manipulating strings

Comment: Ok, you were faster. +1 for speed.

Comment: @kocko: Technically speaking, right; but if one presents this solution in an interview, i'm pretty sure what interviewers next question is....

Comment: Sir, Gyro Gearless as u told interviewers will ask next question related to that what will be that question

Comment: how to do it without using the split method?

Comment: @KaveeshKanwal, although some time has passed, I updated the answer with an approach that doesn't use the `.split()` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "I live in India";
String result = "";
String[] words = str.split(" ");
for (int i=words.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    result = result + words[i] + " ";
}
result = result.subString(result, 0, result.length-1); // remove the last " "
```

This code splits the String along the whitespaces, so that you get an array of the words.
Then a for loop iterates through the array from last to first element and appends the words plus a whitespace to the result string. Finally the whitepace after the last word is removed.

Answer (score -1):

try this way

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        String x="i live in india";
        String y[]=x.split(" ");
        System.out.println(y[3]+" "+y[2]+" "+y[1]+" "+y[0]);
// if the input string is different meaning if the number of words are greater than or less than four then try this way

/*for(int i=y.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            System.out.print(y[i]+ " ");
        }*/
    }

}
```

this is the screenshot to show the output
[image]

Comment: What if the `x` contains 5 words ? :)

Comment: @kocko this will print up to 4 words,This is in accordance with OP qn

Comment: For this string it will work but if input string changes then it will not going to work.

Comment: @Siddh I agree wid you

Comment: @kocko I think my edited answer will work for words greater than four

Comment: @Siddh I think my edited answer will work for words greater than four

Comment: Really ? Let's say `String x = "Hello I am Kocko and I think javabeginner is wrong";`. What your code will output ? :)

Comment: @kocko it will print "wrong is javabeginner think I and Kocko am I Hello"

Comment: @kocko See i have attached a screenshot to justify my answer

Comment: your commented answer should have been your real answer.