# Reversing words individually using a stack

Tags: java, stack

Trying to reverse Strings individually using a stack in java.  I have already wrote a code to output the entire String in reverse, but I need each individual word reversed but kept in the same order.  What could I do to manipulate my code to make this work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import jss2.ArrayStack;

public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = "";
        ArrayStack<String> stack = new ArrayStack<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter a string to be reversed: ");
        str = scanner.nextLine();
        if (str == null || str.equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Try Again!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                    // pushes all the characters in the string
                    // one by one into the Stack

            stack.push(str.substring(i, i + 1));
        }
        String strrev = "";
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {  
                    // pops all the elements from the Stack
                    // one by one which reverses the stack
            strrev += stack.pop();


        }
        System.out.println("Reverse of the string : \"" + strrev + "\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713655/reverse-a-given-sentence-in-java

Comment: You are pushing individual characters, no words.  BTW StringBuilder.reverse() does this if that is all you want.

Comment: Do the same thing word by word...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to break it up in to words, use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).  This will break the string up into words.  You can then reverse the characters in the word either through the code you wrote or as PeterLawrey suggested, create a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and call the "reverse()" method.