# Java : Reverse the String but remain the index of the comma

Tags: java, string

Reversing the string while maintaining the index of COMMA.

the string that need to be reversed : "T,he ,quick, bro,wn f,ox jump,s over, the l,azy do,g".

Expected output: "g,od ,yzal ,eht ,revo, spmuj ,xof nw,orb kc,iuq eh,T"

Comment: Okay, what you have tried so far ? Apart posting here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse a given sentence in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713655/reverse-a-given-sentence-in-java)

Comment: I put the wrong duplicate :<

Comment: what I able to do is reverse the string including the comma,s.   class Reverse {
    public static void main (String [] args){
         String phrase = "\"T,he ,quick, bro,wn f,ox jump,s over, the l,azy do,g\"";
                phrase =new StringBuffer(phrase).reverse().toString();
        System.out.println("the reversed string :" + phrase);
    }
} But i don't know how to make the comma remain at its place .

Answer (score 2):

use `StringBuffer` and `Stack` first remove all commas and save the index of them on stack after reversing insert commas at location that you saved them on stack. use `stringBufferObject.deleteCharAt(index);` for deleting a character and use `stringBufferObject.reverse();` for reversing string.

Comment: +1 Nice answer - enough detail for someone to figure it out, but not a spoon-fed answer. I suspect the OP was hoping for the latter :-)

Answer (score -1):

Here this is code you can use it

```
String original =  "T,he ,quick, bro,wn f,ox jump,s over, the l,azy do,g";

    String reverse = original.replaceAll(",","");
    StringBuilder rev = new StringBuilder(reverse);
    rev = rev.reverse();
    String output="";
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
        if(original.charAt(i) == ','){
            output += ",";
        }else{
            output+=rev.charAt(j++);
        }
    }

     System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: this is the output:g,od yza,l eht ,revo s,pmuj xo,f nw,orb ,kciuq, eh,T

Comment: Expected output: "g,od ,yzal ,eht ,revo, spmuj ,xof nw,orb kc,iuq eh,T"

Comment: I think the output that he want is not same as input

Comment: The index of the commas should be the same in the input and the output.

Comment: I edit My code and fix it. Thank Alexander

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code with your input

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String original =  "T,he ,quick, bro,wn f,ox jump,s over, the l,azy do,g";

         String reverse = "";
          int length = original.length();

          for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
             reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

          System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is: "+reverse);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's wrong. You should read his question again.