# How do you reverse the letters in a string?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766141/reverse-a-string-in-python)

I'm trying to understand how to reverse the letters in a string. Let's say that I have `hello` and am looking for the output `olleh` how would I implement this using the list as a tool?

Comment: There are no arrays in Python.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  What?!?  Check out the `array` module, and be enlightened.

Comment: This is part of my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694977/how-do-you-reverse-the-words-in-a-string-using-python-manually

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The duplicate mentioned does not explain how to reverse a string using lists.

Comment: @cfarm54, why do you want to use lists? What's wrong with just reversing the string?

Comment: @EthanFurman: Apologies, I meant there is no `array` built-in with Python. Clearly there are array implementations. The OP changed this to `list` anyway.

Comment: @Johnsyweb:  It's not builtin, but it is part of the stdlib and has been since before 1.5.

Comment: @EthanFurman: I understand that. Again, apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Using [slice notation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings),

```
forwards = "hello"
backwards = forwards[::-1]
```

(The third section of slice notation is the step; in this case, `-1` makes it step backwards through the entirety of the string, effectively reversing it.)

or, using the `reversed()` function:

```
backwards = ''.join(reversed(forwards))
```

(Note that without the `''.join()`, you'd get a `<reversed object at 0x1215a10>` instead.)

---

```
>>> print backwards
olleh
```

Answer (score 2):

With slice notation:

```
string = "Hello!"
reversed_string = string[::-1]
```