# Reverse String order

Tags: python, string

I want to invert the order of a string. For example: "Joe Red" = "Red Joe"
I believe the reverse method will not help me, since I dont want to reverse every character, just switch words

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you reverse the words in a string using python (manually)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694977/how-do-you-reverse-the-words-in-a-string-using-python-manually)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse the ordering of words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009160/reverse-the-ordering-of-words-in-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to define what you mean by "word".  I'll assume you just want strings of characters separated by whitespace.  In that case, we can do:

```
' '.join(reversed(s.split()))
```

Note, this will remove leading/trailing whitespaces, and convert any consecutive runs of whitespaces to a single space character.

Demo:

```
>>> s = "Red Joe"
>>> ' '.join(reversed(s.split()))
'Joe Red'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
s = "Joe Red"
print ' '.join(s.split()[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ,

```
>>> s= "Joe Red"
>>> words = s.split()
>>> words.reverse()
>>> print ' '.join(words)
Red Joe
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string ="joe red"
string = string.split()
print " ".join(string[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Joe Red"
s= s.split()
c = s[-1]+" "+s[0]
```

c holds "Red Joe".

Comment: what if it is "joe red ram"

Comment: Concatenate the strings by putting a for loop in reverse order! Thanks for the -1!

Comment: @user3193036 -- But to be fair, you didn't mention that as part of your answer and, even if you did, doing repeated concatenations in a for loop leads to quadratic time complexity.  It may (or may not) matter here, BUT, that is why the other answers which use `str.join` are more common idioms in python.  And since they're more common idioms, they're easier for people who have been using the language for a while to read/understand at a glance.

Comment: @user3193036 i dint give u -1.but ur answer only works for two word string. u need give answer which is scalable:)

Comment: Alright, I'll keep all considerations in mind the next time I post an answer. Thanks :)