# Reverse words of a sentence without using String.Split in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, algorithm

Recently I have been asked in a discussion to write an algorithm to implement reverse of words of a sentence (Not reverse of whole sentence) without using string operations such as Split/Replace/Reverse/Join except ToCharArray and Length. The below is what I could devise in 5min of time. Though the algorithm is working fine, it seems bit ugly style of implementation. Can some body help me by polishing the code.

```
string ReverseWords(string s)
{
    string reverseString = string.Empty;
    string word = string.Empty;

    var chars = s.ToCharArray();
    List<ArrayList> words = new List<ArrayList>();
    ArrayList addedChars = new ArrayList();
    Char[] reversedChars = new Char[chars.Length];
    int i = 1;
    foreach (char c in chars)
    {
        if (c != ' ')
        {
            addedChars.Add(c);
        }
        else
        {
            words.Add(new ArrayList(addedChars));
            addedChars.Clear();
        }
        if (i == s.Length)
        {
            words.Add(new ArrayList(addedChars));
            addedChars.Clear();
        }
        i++;
    }
    foreach (ArrayList a in words)
    {
        for (int counter = a.Count - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
        {
            reverseString += a[counter];
        }
        if(reverseString.Length < s.Length)
            reverseString += " ";
    }
    return reverseString;
}
```

Comment: Well if you avoid `Split/Replace/Reverse/Join ...` it is gonna be a bit ugly ! !

Comment: `Reverse` is an extension method of `IEnumerable`, not a string method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is somewhat simpler:

```
string inp = "hai how are you?";
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
List<char> charlist = new List<char>();
for (int c = 0; c < inp.Length; c++ )
{

    if (inp[c] == ' ' || c == inp.Length - 1)
    {
        if (c == inp.Length - 1)
            charlist.Add(inp[c]);
        for (int i = charlist.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            strb.Append(charlist[i]);

        strb.Append(' ');
        charlist = new List<char>();
    }
    else
        charlist.Add(inp[c]);
}
string output = strb.ToString();
```

Comment: This is what the polished version of the above algorithm which  I have asked for. Thanks kovilpatti C sharper

Comment: Here is the another BEST solution -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009160/reverse-the-ordering-of-words-in-a-string

Answer (score 8):

There *is* a relatively **elegant solution which uses a LIFO stack**.
Question however sounds like homework, so I'll only provide the pseudo code.

```
currWord = new LIFO stack of characters
while (! end of string/array)
{
  c = next character in string/array
  if (c == some_white_space_character) {
     while (currWord not empty) {
       c2 = currWord.pop()
       print(c2)
     }
     print(c)
  }
  else
    currWord.push(c)
}
```

Comment: @StanR. I believe you are correct. Interesting concept though.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a polished version:-

```
string words = "hi! how are you!";
string reversedWords = "";

List<int> spaceEncounter = new List<int>();
spaceEncounter.Add(words.Length - 1);

for (int i = words.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{ 
    if(words[i].Equals(' '))
    {
        spaceEncounter.Add(i);

        for (int j = i+1; j < spaceEncounter[spaceEncounter.Count - 2]; j++)
            reversedWords += words[j];

        reversedWords += " ";
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < spaceEncounter[spaceEncounter.Count - 1]; i++)
    reversedWords += words[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small bug in your code. Due to this, the output string would be displayed as `yo are how hi!`, given the input string `hi! how are you`. It's truncating the last char of the last word.

Change this:

```
spaceEncounter.Add(words.Length - 1);
```

To:

```
spaceEncounter.Add(words.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't say anything about the other LINQ extension methods :)

```
static string ReverseWordsWithoutSplit(string input)
{
    var n = 0;
    var words = input.GroupBy(curr => curr == ' ' ? n++ : n);

    return words.Reverse().Aggregate("", (total, curr) => total + string.Concat(curr.TakeWhile(c => c != ' ')) + ' ');
}
```

Comment: :-) Condition is that I shouldn't use framework features such as linq. Thanks for the answer though. It's clean and nice.

Answer (score 1):

One of the Easiest Answer is as given Below please go through it,

```
public static string ReversewordString(string Name)
    {
        string output="";
        char[] str = Name.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (str[i] == ' ')
            {
                output = output + " ";
                for (int j = i + 1; j < str.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (str[j] == ' ')
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    output=output+ str[j];
                }
            }
            if (i == 0)
            {
                output = output +" ";
                int k = 0;
                do
                {
                    output = output + str[k];
                    k++;
                } while (str[k] != ' ');
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
        string temp = string.Empty;
        string reversedString = string.Empty;

        foreach (var currentCharacter in testSentence)
        {
            if (currentCharacter != ' ')
            {
                temp = temp + currentCharacter;
            }
            else
            {
                reversedString = temp + " " + reversedString;
                temp = string.Empty;
            }
        }
        reversedString = temp + " " + reversedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

This version works in-place, without any intermediate data structures. First, it reverses the characters in each word. "me too" => "em oot". Then it reverses the whole string: "em oot" => "too me".

```
    public static string ReverseWords(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            return s;

        char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
        int wordStartIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i]) && wordStartIndex < 0)
            {
                // Remember word start index
                wordStartIndex = i;
            }
            else
            if (wordStartIndex >= 0 && (i == chars.Length-1 || Char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i + 1]))) {
                // End of word detected, reverse the chacacters in the word range
                ReverseRange(chars, wordStartIndex, i);

                // The current word is complete, reset the start index  
                wordStartIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        // Reverse all chars in the string
        ReverseRange(chars, 0, chars.Length - 1);

        return new string(chars);
    }

    // Helper
    private static void ReverseRange(char[] chars, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= (endIndex - startIndex) / 2; i++)
        {
            char tmp = chars[startIndex + i];
            chars[startIndex + i] = chars[endIndex - i];
            chars[endIndex - i] = tmp;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, i know this is an old question but i have been looking for an in place algorithm for the above question. Your solution is the one that closely mimicks mine. I want to know if you have any references that can substantiate your claim that this is indeed in place? It definitely agrees with my understanding of in place but i am concerned at our use of temp variables which, to be fair, are also using memory...

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple recursive function that checks for a " " and then substring accordingly?

```
    private static string rev(string inSent) { 
        if(inSent.IndexOf(" ") != -1) 
        { 
            int space = inSent.IndexOf(" "); 
            System.Text.StringBuilder st = new System.Text.StringBuilder(inSent.Substring(space+1)); 
            return rev(st.ToString()) + " " + inSent.Substring(0, space); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return inSent; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: This is Java not C# !

Comment: Either way, logic...

Now spot the difference and be sure to use System.Text.

Answer (score 0):

use stack in C#

```
string str = "ABCDEFG";
Stack<char> stack=new Stack<char>();
foreach (var c in str)
{
    stack.Push(c);
}
char[] chars=new char[stack.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    chars[i]=stack.Pop();
}
var result=new string(chars); //GFEDCBA
```