# Creating the mirror image file in UNIX

Tags: unix

I want to create a mirror image of the file in UNIX.
Example:

Input file:
Alex
12345
john
Bravo

Output should be:
Bravo 
john
12345
Alex

Any help would be appreciated..!!

Comment: Have you tried: `man cp`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your attempts and at what point you have difficulties.

Comment: You'll get a million results upon searching for "reverse line" or whatever. Posting it here would require more effort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse the ordering of words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009160/reverse-the-ordering-of-words-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use awk:

```
awk '{for (i=NF;i>=1; i--) printf("%s ", $i); print ""}' inFile
```

Comment: there is some more info here: http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/156503-reversing-line-word-order-using-awk.html