# How do I select when to print specific characters in a character array

Tags: c, arrays, character

For my assignment I need to do the following

- Ask the user to input their name and save it to a character array
- Then I need to output the number of characters input by said user
- Then I have to spell that user's name backwards
- followed by telling the user which part of the character array contained the space between their first and last name
- The last thing that I need to do but can't quiet figure out (actually I'm completely lost) is output the user's last name first then first name last (ie John Doe = Doe John);

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int main ()
  {
  printf("Enter your name\n");

  char name [25]={'\0'};
  char * pch;

  fgets(name,sizeof(name),stdin); 

  printf("You Entered: %s     \n", name);

  printf("There are %u characters in your name including the space. \n", strlen(name));

  char end;
  int i;
  end = strlen(name) -1;
  printf("Your name backwards is");
  for (i = end; i >= 0; --i)
  {
  printf("%c", name [i]);
  }

  printf("\nLooking for the space in your name \n", name);
  pch=strchr(name, ' ');
  while (pch!=NULL)
  {
      printf("Space found at %d\n", pch-name+1);
      pch=strchr(pch+1, ' ');
  }


  }
  ```

Anyone that knows how to do this Can you please explain what you did so I can learn from you?

Comment: So if entered name is `John Doe` -- you wants to print `Doe John` **?**

Comment: I don't get the second bullet

Comment: Yes correct, the second bullet means "eoD nhoJ"

Comment: In simply sentence you want `ABC XYZ` to be printed as `XYZ ABC` ?

Comment: @user2172993 then what's difference between 2nd and 3rd bullet, frame your question properly, in fact your title is nothing related too

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: @POW The second means tell the user how many characters they input (ie John Doe is 8 characters w/ space). The third bullet means to print the name completely backwards.

Comment: +1 For a learner starting out with `fgets()` rather than `scanf()` or `gets()`.

Comment: `fgets()` will cause `name` to likely end with `\n` that you may want to set to `\0` before further processing.

Comment: Aside: Consider `%zu` with `strlen(name)`.  `strlen()` returns type `size_t`, `%u` is for `unsigned`.  `%zu` is for `size_t`.

Comment: Aside: `char end; int i;` should be the same type, ideally `size_t`, but `int` will work for now.  For future ref: You are doing a scary `strlen(name) - 1`.  With robust code, using `size_t` & under special circumstances, strlen(name) could be 0 and `end` will be a huge value.  You could instead do `size_t end = strlen(name); for (size_t i = end; i > 0; ) { printf("%c", name [--i]); }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting segmentation fault (cord dumped)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055085/why-am-i-getting-segmentation-fault-cord-dumped)

Answer (score 1):

Since you found the space, cut the string in half there by overwriting it with a `'\0'` character:

```
*pch = '\0';
```

Then print first the string following where the space was, and then the whole string:

```
printf("last name: %s\n", pch + 1);
printf("first name: %s\n", name);
```

This will break somewhat if there are multiple spaces, but you get the idea.

Comment: I don't think I can do this because I need to be able to use it for others when they enter their name as well.

Comment: I had exactly the same idea, you just beat me to it.

Comment: @user2172993 When other enter their name via a subsequent `fgets()`, the `\0` inserted here is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You know the index where the space occured(`pch` here). Print `pch+1` to `end` and then from `0` to `pch` if you are iterating the string by character.

Answer (score 1):

You already found the location where the space in the name is in the second to last question. Just replace the space with a `\0`. Then printf the two strings:

```
*pch = '\0';
printf("%s %s\n",pch + 1,name);
```

Comment: I'm getting a segmentation faul (core dumped) error when I try this.

Comment: Maybe OP is doing this after the while loop rather than inside it?

Comment: That makes sense - since at that point, pch is pointing to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

> The last thing that I need to do but can't quiet figure out (actually
>   I'm completely lost) is output the users last name first then first
>   name last (ie John Doe = Doe John);

It is common assignment/interview question of how to reverse an oder of strings in an array. An elegant albeit maybe not the most efficient algorithm would be:

```
step 1: reverse the array character by character 
step 2: reverse each string in-place
```

Check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009160/reverse-the-ordering-of-words-in-a-string) for more info.