# Why am I getting segmentation fault (cord dumped)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

After having the user input their first and last name I need the program to do multiple things which are all working just fine except I need to program to print their name in reverse order (John Doe = Doe John). I think I have the proper function in their because of the help I received from you guys, but I'm still getting a segmentation fault. What's the problem here.

It's the last function in the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    printf("Enter your first and last name\n");

    char name [25]={'\0'};
    char * space;

    fgets(name,sizeof(name),stdin);

    printf("You Entered: %s     \n", name);

    printf("There are %u characters in your name including the space. \n", strlen(name));

    char end;
    int i;
    end = strlen(name) -1;
    printf("Your name backwards is");
    for (i = end; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        printf("%c", name [i]);
    }

    printf("\nLooking for the space in your name \n", name);
    space=strchr(name, ' ');
    while (space!=NULL)
    {
        printf("The space was found at character %d\n", space-name+1);
        space=strchr(space+1, ' ');
    }
    //Why am I getting a segmentation fault (cord dumped) error here?
    *space = '\0';
    printf(" %s %s ", space+1, name);

}
```

Comment: You are posting same question again and again, for example recently you posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054199/how-do-i-select-when-to-print-specific-characters-in-a-character-array) You got reasonable answers there. Please put some efforts to understand.

Answer (score 3):

When while loop breaks `space` is NULL, you are writing on NULL address.

```
while (space!=NULL) <-- "loop breaks when space is NULL"
{
    printf("The space was found at character %d\n", space-name+1);
    space=strchr(space+1, ' ');
}
//Why am I getting a segmentation fault (cord dumped) error here? 
*space = '\0';  <--- "space is NULL"
```

**Edit:**

To print entered words in reverse order, try following code (read comments to understand):

```
// suppose name is "Grijesh    Chauhan"
char *last = NULL, *firstspcae = NULL; 
firstspcae = space = strchr(name, ' ');
*firstspcae = '\0';  // At first space insert nul char '\0'
while (space != NULL)
{
    printf("The space was found at character %d\n", space-name+1);
    last = space + 1;  //next to space 
    space=strchr(space + 1, ' ');
}
printf("\n%s %s ", last, name);   // "Chauhan Grijesh"
*firstspcae = ' ';  // recover your original  string back 
printf("\n%s %s ", last, name);  // "Grijesh    Chauhan"
```

Comment: So what do you suggest I do? I need help, I'm just a beginner obviously so any example you can give me so I can learn from it would be great.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan its in the question. He's trying to take a proper name and flip the words, but not the letters.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I don't know what to try now, I've sadly been working on this program for hours. I'm looking to you guys for help solving my problem.

Comment: @user2172993 wait let me read... do you want If I enter `"Grijesh Chauhan"` output of last line is `"Chauhan Grijesh"` **?**

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I need to happen

Comment: @user2172993 Does your homework specifically state you need to flip the names *in the same array they were read in to* ? Its trivial regardless, but if that isn't a restriction its even simpler.

Comment: @WhozCraig No it doesn't, but would like to learn how to do it using this one array if you don't mind.

Comment: @user2172993 You have technical mistake rather logical check this --[working code](http://codepad.org/afkiPsQy)

Comment: @user2172993 let me know if you don't understand any thing.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Awesome, I got it to work. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: @user2172993 Good, your welcome. As I comment to your question put some effort to understand answer. Second always accept an answer read: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) I saw you don't accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

a more general way to find out in what line you're getting your segfault , compile your program with `gcc`using the `-g` flag (e.g `gcc -g file.c`) then run `gdb'` (e.g `gdb a.out`) then type `run` then `where` it should give you the line of the segfault (or any error of the sort) and the reason behind it