# reverse order of a string in C++

Tags: c++

I have a c++ program where it take data from a file.
In file data is as follows:

this is line 1

this is line 2

this is line 3

Here's how I read it.

```
ifstream file;
std::string list[max], temp;

file.open("file");
int i=0;
while ( getline (file, temp )) //while the end of file is NOT reached
{
    list[i] = temp;
    i++;
}
file.close();
```

Now what I do is run a loop as follows

```
for(i=0; i<no_of_lines; i++){
    temp = list[i];


}
```

What i want is to reverse the line. For example in line 1 data is
 'this is line 1' and update data in temp as '1 line is this'

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `std::string reverse(list[i].rbegin(), list[i].rend());`

Comment: You want to reverse the words, but not every individual letter, correct?

Comment: Put your question in the post, not somewhere in your code. (That alone, by the way, doth it not a good question make.)

Comment: yes you are right @NKamrath

Comment: Ok, then Borgleader's answer will not work for what you want just fyi.  Also, take Jongware's advice, put the question as text, not in code please!

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125096/reverse-order-of-words-in-string?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse the ordering of words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009160/reverse-the-ordering-of-words-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead of fixed array and [std::reverse](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/). This solution will also make your code valid for any number of input strings.

Complete code:

```
typedef vector<string> StrVec;

ifstream file;
string temp;
StrVec strings;

file.open("file");
while(getline (file, temp))
{
    strings.push_back(temp);
}
file.close()

printf("Before reverse:\n\n");
for(StrVec::iterator i = strings.begin(); i != strings.end(); ++i)
{
    printf("%s\n", i->c_str());
}

std::reverse(strings.begin(), strings.end());

printf("\nAfter reverse:\n\n");
for(StrVec::iterator i = strings.begin(); i != strings.end(); ++i)
{
    printf("%s\n", i->c_str());
}
```