# split string in python where removing first number

Tags: python-3.x, split

I am currently solving a ques which requires me to calculate this expression

> 1 2 1
>  1 4 6 4 1
>   1 5 10 10 5 1

Now **my approach** :
 
I calculate value till half. using the formula nCr. ex

> 1 2
>   1 4 6
>  1 5 10

as the same sequence is getting repeated i can copy the same sequence at the back to get the desired output.
 
Now the **problem**. 
I store `1 5 10` in a string and i reverse it by word using. `" ".join(stri.split()[::-1])` which i learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009160/reverse-the-ordering-of-words-in-a-string) and it gives the output 1 5 10 10 5 1
now what i cannot do is. `1 2 1`
from `1 2` after reversing it I want to remove the first number like from 1 `2 2 1` i want to delete one 2
How do i go about i.?
What would be it's syntax.

Help appreciated

Comment: `I store 1 5 10 in a string` - store it in a list and reverse it

Comment: I did the same for 1 5 10 problem is in 1 2 1