# Excel matching letters

Tags: excel

I'm trying to have a way in Excel that allows me to say that

**ABC-DEF** is the same as **DEF-ABC**

Anyone know a trick on how to do that?

Comment: Do you want the matching to be case-sensitive (i.e. ABC is the same as AbC)? Is the format XXX-YYY fixed (i.e. two strings of length 3 separated by an hyphen)? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
=IF(D2>H2,CONCATENATE(D2,"-",H2),CONCATENATE(H2,"-",D2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, but only sometimes, (featuring *manchmal aber nur manchmal*) you may get lucky posting a question like this getting answered:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    
    Debug.Print CompareMe("ABC-DEF", "DEF-ABC")
    Debug.Print CompareMe("ABC-DEF", "DEF-AAC")
    
End Sub

Public Function CompareMe(strCompareA As String, strCompareB As String, Optional strDelim = "-")

    Dim arrA    As Variant
    Dim arrB    As Variant
    
    arrA = Split(strCompareA, strDelim)
    arrB = Split(strCompareB, strDelim)
    
    CompareMe = (arrA(0) = arrB(1) And arrA(1) = arrB(0))

End Function
```

Check the `TestMe` sub, it prints the result in the console.

---

Furthermore, [this is an interview algorithm question, asked by Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009160/reverse-the-ordering-of-words-in-a-string). This is a general working answer - *reverse the whole string, then split by word and reverse each word*. This is how to do it with VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print strReverseOrder("ABC-DEF-GHI")
    Debug.Print strReverseOrder("ABC-DEF") = "DEF-ABC"
    
End Sub

Public Function strReverseOrder(strToReverse As String, Optional strDelim = "-")

    Dim strWorking          As String
    Dim arrWorking()        As String
    Dim lngCounter          As Long
    Dim strAnswer           As String
    
    strWorking = StrReverse(strToReverse)
    arrWorking = Split(strWorking, strDelim)
    
    For lngCounter = LBound(arrWorking) To UBound(arrWorking)
        strAnswer = IIf(lngCounter = LBound(arrWorking), vbNullString, strAnswer & strDelim) & StrReverse(arrWorking(lngCounter))
    Next lngCounter

    strReverseOrder = strAnswer

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here’s the formula

```
=IF(AND(RIGHT(A8,3)=LEFT(A9,3),LEFT(A8,3)=RIGHT(A9,3)),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is `A1` put this in `B1`: `=IF(A1="ABC-DEF","DEF-ABC",A1)`. Drag down to fill in.

Comment: How does that relate to the issue?

Comment: @teylyn the question, as I read it, this is what the issue is; he/she wants to get the "abc..." as "def...." assuming this is in a column. The question is open for interpretation and this might be one solution.

Comment: The question is open to interpretation. So far so good. The way I read it is A1 has "ABC-DEF" and B1 has "DEF-ABC". Create a formula in C1 that compares the two cells and shows "TRUE". You don't compare two values. You only take one and make an assumption.

Comment: the assumption is this; if "ABD-DEF" is the same as "DEF-ABC" then there wouldn't be any need for column A. What he/she wants to do with this result, that I cant predict. This only moves all values from `A` over to `B` and replaces "ABC-DEF"

Comment: You're not getting the point. Two cells. Compare them and determine if their content is the same. One has "ABC-DEF", the other has "DEF-ABC". How would you do it? Your approach does not take into consideration two cells, but just one. You are not comparing anything.

Comment: thats not the question either. Question is only to get them to be the same. But I see your point, and i agree with you on that.
Vityata's answer looks for me to be the way in VBA.