# c program on reversing a sentence

Tags: c, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Given an array of characters which form a sentence of words, give an efficient algorithm to reverse the order of the words (not characters) in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402/given-an-array-of-characters-which-form-a-sentence-of-words-give-an-efficient-a)

For example if i give a input as "This is a string"
I should get the output as "string a is This"
I cant get any idea on how to do it

Comment: hint: it can also be solved recursively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First Reverse the string in place

Then Reverse each word in place (words are delimited by a space)

Comment: Yeah, you just solved his homework.

Comment: @Aleš Keprt : No, I didn't write his code for him. I gave him a hint.

Comment: Another hint: note that the routine you write to reverse the whole sentence can also be used to reverse individual words, if you think about it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find all the words then print them in reverse order. Just remember they're separated by spaces. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void Reverse(char *,char * );

 char str[100];

void main(){

char *start,*end,i=0;

printf("\nEnter: ");

scanf("%[^\n]s",str);        //similar to gets()

start=str;

while(*(str+i)!='\0') i++;

end=str+i-1;


Reverse(start,end);

printf("\nstr:%s",str);

end=str;

for(i=0;*(str+i)!='\0';i++){


  if(*(str+i)==' ' ){
     Reverse(start,end-1);
     start=end+1;
     end=start;
     continue;
  }
  end++;
}

Reverse(start,end-1);

printf("\nstr:%s",str);  

  }

 void Reverse(char *start,char *end){

char temp=0,i=0;

while(start<end) {

  temp=*start;

  *start=*end;

  *end=temp;

  start++;

  end--; 

}

}
```

Comment: You should probably explain your code.