# Parallel to PHP's "explode" in C: Split char* into char* using delimiter

Tags: php, c, explode, strtok

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string with delimiters in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c)

I'm searching a good way to ["explode"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) a char* into other char* using a delimiter.

My delimiter will be `#`

Comment: Are you looking for something like [strtok](http://www.elook.org/programming/c/strtok.html)?

Comment: Nothing at this time, just searching for a good way to do it.
Here is what i'm thinking;
Loop trough the char array, and copy each char into the other char*, and this until the current char is my delimiter.

Comment: see [examples how to split a sentence into words](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47402/4279)

Comment: "explode" is a function name that [I'm hardly surprised to find is common in PHP](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `strtok` like CrazyCasta said but his/hers code is wrong.

```
char *tok;
char *src = malloc(strlen(srcStr) + 1);
memcpy(src, srcStr);

tok = strtok(src, "#");
if(tok == NULL)
{
    printf("no tokens found");
    free(src);
    return ???;
}
printf("%s ; ", tok);
while((tok = strtok(NULL, "#")))
    printf("%s ; ", tok);
printf("\n");
free(str);
```

Be aware that `strtok` has to be called the first time with the source pointer, after that you have to use `NULL`. Also `src` must be writeable because `strtok` writes `\0` to terminate the found strings. Hence, depending on how you read the string (and whether you are going to use it afterwards or not), you should do a copy of it. But as I said, this is not always necessary.

EDIT:

an `explode` function could look like this:

```
char *strdup(const char *src)
{
    char *tmp = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
    if(tmp)
        strcpy(tmp, src);
    return tmp;
}

void explode(const char *src, const char *tokens, char ***list, size_t *len)
{   
    if(src == NULL || list == NULL || len == NULL)
        return;

    char *str, *copy, **_list = NULL, **tmp;
    *list = NULL;
    *len  = 0;

    copy = strdup(src);
    if(copy == NULL)
        return;

    str = strtok(copy, tokens);
    if(str == NULL)
        goto free_and_exit;

    _list = realloc(NULL, sizeof *_list);
    if(_list == NULL)
        goto free_and_exit;

    _list[*len] = strdup(str);
    if(_list[*len] == NULL)
        goto free_and_exit;
    (*len)++;


    while((str = strtok(NULL, tokens)))
    {   
        tmp = realloc(_list, (sizeof *_list) * (*len + 1));
        if(tmp == NULL)
            goto free_and_exit;

        _list = tmp;

        _list[*len] = strdup(str);
        if(_list[*len] == NULL)
            goto free_and_exit;
        (*len)++;
    }


free_and_exit:
    *list = _list;
    free(copy);
}
```

then you have to call it:

```
char **list;
size_t i, len;
explode("this;is;a;string", ";", &list, &len);
for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    printf("%d: %s\n", i+1, list[i]);

/* free list */
for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    free(list[i]);
free(list);
```

this is an example running with valgrind:

```
valgrind ./a 
==18675== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18675== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al. 
==18675== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18675== Command: ./a 
==18675== 
1: this
2: is
3: a
4: string
==18675== 
==18675== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18675==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18675==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 114 bytes allocated
==18675== 
==18675== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18675== 
==18675== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18675== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Apparently my compiler is a bit picky so I had to specify the return types for malloc and realloc. `char *tmp = (char*)malloc(strlen(src) + 1);` and `tmp = (char**)realloc(_list, (sizeof * _list) * (*len + 1));` and `_list = (char**)realloc(NULL, sizeof * _list);` ... hope that bit helps someone.

Comment: @VinceK you are probably using a C++ compiler, a C compiler should not require you to cast a `void*` to another pointer.

Comment: You are correct @Pablo

Comment: @VinceK be aware of compiling C code with a C++ compiler. There are some differences and you might end up with strange results. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201593/where-is-c-not-a-subset-of-c

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is what the [strtok](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html) function is for:

```
char* tok;
tok = strtok(srcStr, "#");

while(tok != NULL)
{
    // Do stuff with tok
    tok = strtok(NULL, "#");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `strtok` is the correct call, but you're using it in the wrong way :(

Comment: Durp, thx. It's been a while since I've actually used it.

Comment: yeah, I always have to take a look at the man pages before using it