# What is the Big-O of this function that reverses words in a string

Tags: python, big-o, time-complexity

I have a simple function, reverseWords(), that reveses the words in a string. eg. an input of a S = "this is a string" gives an output of "siht si a gnirts"

I was wondering what the big O of this function is. Is it O(N), O(N^2), or O(N* M)?

```
def reverseWords(S):
    # code in Python 2.7
    listA = S.split()
    output = []
    for element in listA:
        output.append(element[::-1])

    return (" ".join(output))
```

Is it O(N), O(N^2), or O(N* M)?

- O(N^2) because we have a nested loop eg. passing over input once, outer loop, and then reversing each character as the inner loop
- O(N*M) same reason as above except M is denoted as the looping over the characters
- O(N) because... I forgot the explanation

Comment: The most entertaining way to find the answer to this question is to create various sample inputs and test it. :)

Comment: Hint: `reverse` is O(N) and looping is O(M) (M is the length of `listA`)!

Comment: related: [Efficiently reverse the order of the words (not characters) in an array of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/47402/4279)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's `O(N)`. I assume the part you're unsure about is:

```
for element in listA:
    output.append(element[::-1])
```

The thing to note here is that although we do have nested loops (over `listA` and over the characters in each element of it), the total number of characters processed is still only `O(N)`. If `k` is the average number of letters in each word, then you can think of the time as `N/k` (for the outer loop) * `k` (for the inner loop) = `N`.

A more direct (I'd say better) way to analyse it is to think, "what do I need to do for each character"?:

- scan over it looking for word boundaries in `split()`
- copy it to a new string in `split()`
- append that new string to a result list (actually we do this less than once per character, but an upper bound is fine for big-O)
- advance the iterator over `listA` (again, less than once, only once for each word)
- copy it in reverse order into a new string in the slice.
- append its containing string to `output` (once for each word)
- whatever `join()` does (which I invite you to investigate if you care, or take my word that it's `O(total length of all strings)`).

Therefore, provided that the list appends, memory allocation, and whatnot, are all amortised `O(1)`, which in CPython they are, then the overall time complexity is `O(N)` including the `join()`.

And since correct terminology is important, since it's `O(N)` it therefore is also `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply reassign from the last index value to a new array through a single for loop.

```
function reversString(stringArg)
{
  arrOfstring = stringArg.split("")
  let revers = []
  for(let i = 0; i <arrOfstring.length; i++)
    {
      let j= arrOfstring.length -1 -i
      revers[i] = arrOfstring[j]

    }
  return revers.join("")
    
}

console.log(reversString("hello world !"))
```

thanx